# How I can convert publishedAt to date and time

Tags: php, youtube-api

I got publishedAt result from `Youtube API` but I want convert it to date and time using php how I can do that ?

> Published At Text : 2018-08-14T14:30:02.000Z

Comment: Show us what have you tried, tell us what happened, and we can guide from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As gray said you can use strtotime() and date() to format the date.

```
$googleTime = '2018-08-14T14:30:02.000Z';
$strtotimeFormat = strtotime($googleTime);
$dateTimeFormat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $strtotimeFormat)
var_dump($dateTimeFormat)
```

OUTPUT: '2018-08-14 14:30:02'

Answer (score -1):

You can pass it to strtotime() or to DateTime constructor

```
>>> strtotime('2018-08-14T14:30:02.000Z')
=> 1534257002
>>> new DateTime('2018-08-14T14:30:02.000Z')
=> DateTime @1534257002 {#3353
     date: 2018-08-14 14:30:02.0 +00:00,
   }
```